# Wpf: Apply custom style of ToolTip at multiple controls

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip, styles, controltemplate

I am working with WPF application. I have created a custom control library where I have customized all controls, meaning added some functionality and restyled them. Same way I have restyled the ToolTip as well. I am using this custom library in other projects. Everything is working fine except ToolTip. ToolTip style is not getting applied. Any Help plz.

#### Edit:

I have created a custom class named ToolTip that derives from System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip, I have declared style for my custom class as well. Now I want to know how can I get this style applied for ToolTip of each control, I mean I want to create object of my ToolTip whenever user set ToolTip on a control.

in .cs:

```
public class ToolTip : System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip
{
    static ToolTip()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ToolTip), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ToolTip)));
    }
}
```

in .xaml(Resource Dictionary):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="-2" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ToolTip}">
                <Grid Name="Border" Background="Transparent" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <Rectangle RadiusX="7.5" RadiusY="7.5">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,-0.5" EndPoint="0.547,0.913">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFEEEEEE" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFBBBBBB" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextBlock.Foreground="Black" TextBlock.FontSize="12" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any Help plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing the default ToolTip Style in a shared ResourceDictionary in a separate assembly will allow it to be used by multiple projects. You can merge in the MyDefaultStyles ResourceDictionary in the Resources folder of the SharedStyleLibrary.dll into App.xaml using:

```
  <App.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/SharedStyleLibrary;component/Resources/MyDefaultStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </App.Resources>
```

If MyDefaultStyles contains an implicit ToolTip Style (`<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">`
) it will be used as the default. You can also target it more locally by instead giving the Style an x:Key and then creating an implicit ToolTip Style in whatever scope you want it to apply (i.e. Window, UserControl, single layout Panel):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ExternalLibraryNamedStyle}">...
```

Answer (score 2):

If your custom `ToolTip` class is only for the sake of applying templates, it's much easier to use an Implicit Style for your ToolTips:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <!-- rest of your style here -->
</Style>
```

Comment: Using this approach doesn't suit my scenario, as I have to use this style in multiple projects.....thats why I am using custom control library approach.......customizing control at one place and using in multiple projects of my application.....I don't want to declare styles for all controls in each project separately........then it will n't be easy to maintain.

Comment: @viky - Why don't you use a library with a shared ResourceDictionary that you can merge into App.xaml in each of your projects?

Comment: The approach suggested by John above is the one used in the Silverlight Toolkit themes, for example. It uses implicit styles for each control type.

Comment: @John Bowen: Thanks a lot, Plz post it as an answer, so that I can accept it.