# WPF: Style ToolTip with Image

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, tooltip

Is it possible to create a style for ToolTip that would place an image next to the Item on which the tool tip resides and then show the tool tip text when the user hovers over the image?  Something like this:

[image]

Currently I am doing a StackPanel to add the image with the tool tip like so:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox Content="Reload Employee Data"
              IsChecked="{Binding AdjustmentSettings.ReloadEmployeeData}" 
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="0">
    </CheckBox>
    <Image Source="/DelphiaLibrary;Component/Resources/info.ico" 
           ToolTip="Check if you want to re-upload ...."/>
</StackPanel>
```

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, I am looking for a way to style ToolTip such that if I define ToolTip on any object (i.e., Button, CheckBox, etc.) the info image is shown and the tool tip text is placed on this info image.

I would like to be able to do something like this and still get the same as the stack panel above:

```
<CheckBox Content="Reload Employee Data"
                  IsChecked="{Binding AdjustmentSettings.ReloadEmployeeData}" 
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  ToolTip="Blah blah blah..."
                  Style="{StaticResource ToolTipImageStyle}">
</CheckBox>
```

And be able to apply this ToolTipImageStyle to any control (i.e., Button, CheckBox, TextBox, etc.).  If that isn't possible can I style an individual control and just create different styles for different controls (one for buttons, another for TextBlock, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. I couldn't figure out the color so just change that.

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847734/wpf-image-tooltip)

[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807354/backgroundcolor-of-entire-tooltip)

```
<Image Source="/DelphiaLibrary;Component/Resources/info.ico" Width="25" Height="25">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Background="LightBlue">
            <TextBlock Width="200" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
                Check if you want to re-upload table foxpro.hrpersnl from the source. <LineBreak />
                Leave unchecked to use existing data that has been previously uplaoded.
            </TextBlock>
        </ToolTip>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

[image]

**Update 1:**

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228954/common-tooltip-style-in-wpf)

In the App.xaml add this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" >
                    <TextBox Background="LightBlue" Width="200" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{TemplateBinding ToolTip.Content}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then in your XAML file change to:

*Note*: This will work with all object's tool tips.

```
<Image Source="Images/MenuImageZoomOut.png" Width="25" Height="25"
           ToolTip="Check if you want to re-upload table foxpro.hrpersnl from the source. Leave unchecked to use existing data that has been previously uplaoded." />
```

The image:

[image]

If this doesn't work, try this: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385068/wpf-apply-custom-style-of-tooltip-at-multiple-controls)

Comment: I am not looking for just an image with a tooltip but rather a way to make a style of the entire stackpanel.  Seen my edits in the OP.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but I am not looking to simply style the ToolTip itself.  I am looking for a way to automatically apply an image to a control (Checkbox, Button, TextBlock, etc.) when that control's ToolTip is defined.  Then have the that control's tool tip text appear when the user hovers over the image.